# How to put a proper error message while entering any alphabet or special character in <input matInput type="number">?

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have tried to do in the Component

1. `min = 0; port: new FormControl('', [this.validatePort(this.min)]),`
2. `port: new FormControl('', Validators.required)`

and in html

```
<mat-form-field class="inputnumber">
  <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Port" formControlName="port" required>
     <mat-error>
            {{errors.port}}
     </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

I want to restrict alphabet and special character entry in input type number with some proper error message. Currently, If I entered alphabet or special character unable to write but want to show some error message for this.

I am using angular 7.2.2

Comment: Hi, are you using angular 1.7 or Angular 7?

Comment: BTW, I think you should add Validators and only display the error when there's an error (you can handle it using an `if condition`).
Here is the link for the Angular Validators: https://angular.io/api/forms/Validators

Comment: @Sarkar Have added an answer check once

Comment: @Alberto,Using Angular 7.

Answer (score 0):

This will do what you want:

Set `min` and `max` for `FormControl` in Component.ts

HTML Code:

```
<mat-form-field class="inputnumber">
  <input matInput type="number" placeholder="Enter Port" [formControl]="port" required>
   <mat-error *ngIf="port.invalid">
     Your Error Message
   </mat-error>
</mat-form-field>
```

TS code:

```
port = new FormControl('', [Validators.required, Validators.max(15), Validators.min(0)]);
```

<kbd>[`Stackblitz`](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zk4b8v)</kbd>

Comment: But this code is also allowing user to type alphabets and special characters ,though it is not showing(my current application code is with this type logic only).But I need to show some error message whenever user will try to type something else apart from number in that input.

Comment: yes, you have to create your custom regEx using the Validators property

Comment: @S.Sarkar Try this pattern:(?<=\s|^)\d+(?=\s|$)